# Databind repeater using Linq with group by

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, .net-4.0

I need to bind a repeater with hierarchical data as follows:

```
Category1
   - Item1
   - Item2
Category2
   - Item3
   - Item4
```

I currently have a single dataset with the items as well as the category that each item belongs to.

I'm trying to learn Linq and was wondering if there was a way I can do the same using Linq?

Below is what I tried:

```
var groupbyfilter = from dr in dtListing.AsEnumerable()
                            group dr by dr["Category"];
        DataTable dtFinal = dtListing.Clone();

  foreach (var x in groupbyfilter)
          x.CopyToDataTable(dtFinal, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);


  rptList.DataSource = dtFinal;
  rptList.DataBind();
```

But trouble with it is it repeats category for each item.

Comment: check this might help you : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/GroupedRepeater.aspx

Comment: Thanks Pranay, but I'm trying to do it using Linq.

Comment: It's not clear what it is you want to have output.  Including the item template or exactly what you're looking for might help.  For instance, how is what you want different from just ordering by category instead of grouping by it?

Comment: If I simply order by category, it repeats category multiple times. What I need is category title to be the heading, followed by the items that appear in that category. Then the next category title, followed by items in that category. Hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need a repeater nested inside another.

Do a distinct on the `dtlisting` selecting only the category field. Bind this to the outer repeater.

In the 2nd repeater, select data whose where condition has category field which equals to the value that is being databound to the repeater item. You'd have to handle this in the repeater's `onitem_databound` event.

Here is an example.

```
<%@ Import  Namespace="System.Data" %>
      <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <div>
                  Category: <b><%# Container.DataItem%></b>
                  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
                      <FooterTemplate>
                          <%="</ul>" %>
                      </FooterTemplate>
                      <HeaderTemplate>
                          <%= "<ul>"%>
                      </HeaderTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <li>
                              <%# ((Data.DataRow)Container.DataItem)[1] %>, <%#  ((Data.DataRow)Container.DataItem)[0] %>
                          </li>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:Repeater>
              </div>                
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
```

For this sample I used a csv as my datasource, and created a datatable using it. So my codebehind looks like:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataTable csvData;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        csvData = Utils.csvToDataTable("data.csv", true);
        GridView1.DataSource = csvData;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        Repeater1.DataSource =
            (from x in csvData.AsEnumerable() select x["category"]).Distinct();
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item |
                e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
            Repeater rptr = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("Repeater2");
            rptr.DataSource =
                csvData.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x["category"].Equals(e.Item.DataItem));
            rptr.DataBind();
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed. Have just made a couple of tiny edits to code to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use nested repeaters like deostroll says, or specify a grouping field and have a group header in your ItemTemplate that's dynamically hidden (or rendered) every time your grouping field changes.

More detail in fernan's answer at http://forums.asp.net/t/1252235.aspx