# DNN 7 Nested Repeater with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dotnetnuke

I have used this answer in the below link as an example.  But I can't get the Imports statement to work in the ASCX file. Is there any way to do the display data in the inner repeater so I don't have to import that namespace?  Error with namespace in the ascx file - 
"error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Data' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ---> System.Web.HttpCompileException: "

[Databind repeater using Linq with group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508051/databind-repeater-using-linq-with-group-by)

ASCX

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="View.ascx.cs" Inherits="Christoc.Modules.ProductFilter.View" %>
<%@ Import  Namespace="System.Data" %>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCategories" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptCategories_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <div>
        Category: <b><%# Container.DataItem%></b>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptOptions" runat="server">
            <FooterTemplate>
                <%="</ul>" %>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <%= "<ul>"%>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <%# ((Data.DataRow)Container.DataItem)[1] %>, <%#  ((Data.DataRow)Container.DataItem)[0] %>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>                
</ItemTemplate>
```

Code Behind

```
var cc = new CategoryMappingsController();
            var listview = cc.ListCategories(ModuleId);
            catOptData = listview.ConvertToDataTable(record => new object[] { listview });
            rptCategories.DataSource = (from x in catOptData.AsEnumerable() select x["CategoryName"]).Distinct(); ;
            rptCategories.DataBind();
```

bound function

```
protected void rptCategories_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item | e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Repeater rptr = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptOptions");
            rptr.DataSource = catOptData.AsEnumerable();//.Where(x => x["CategoryName"].Equals(e.Item.DataItem));
            rptr.DataBind();

            Repeater NestedRepeater = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("NestedRepeater");
            NestedRepeater.DataSource = e.Item.DataItem;
            NestedRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing `System.Data` but using `Data.xxx` in code. The compiler cannot find the `Data` namespace without help. Either drop `.Data` form the import or `Data.` from the code. I would suggest the latter.

```
<%@ Import  Namespace="System.Data" %>
```

Or:

```
<%# ((DataRow)Container.DataItem)[1] %>, <%#  ((DataRow)Container.DataItem)[0] %>
```