# VB.net - iterate through collection, create repeaters that group items with same value?

Tags: vb.net, webforms

Let's see if I can explain this properly without making everyone read more than is really needed.

If I have a List of objects with the following values (in reality it is much more complex, but figuring it out for a basic version should be enough):

```
int id = 1
string style = "basic"
string color = "red"

int id = 2
string style = "basic"
string color = "blue"

int id = 3
string style = "advanced"
string color = "green"

int id = 4
string style = "basic"
string color = "purple"

int id = 5
string style = "advanced"
string color = "yellow"
```

When using a repeater on the page, I naturally end up with 5 items since there are 5 "sets" of values.

What I need to do is instead of ending up with 5, I need to group by the style and end up with 2 instances, where one of them contains 3 items and the other contains 2.

So, instead of displaying this (one repeater with 5 items):

id:1  style:basic  color:red
id:2  style:basic  color:blue
id:3  style:advanced  color:green
id:4  style:basic  color:purple
id:5  style:advanced  color:yellow

I'd like to end up with this  (two different versions of the same repeater, where one has 3 items and the other has 2).

id: 1 color: red
id: 2 color: blue
id: 4 color: purple

id: 3 color: green
id: 5 color: yellow

So, basically no matter how big my list is, I want to look at the "style" parameter and render a new repeater "group" for everything with the same value.

If I had 75 objects in the list and 25 of them were style = "a" and 25 were style ="b" and 25 were style = "c" then my page would render with 3 blocks of 25 each.  Or there could be 74 of style = "a" and only 1 of style = "b".  Or all of them are the same style.  This is not known in advance.

Like I said, the real situation has a lot more going on, but I'm trying to avoid making everyone's eyes glaze.

Thank you.

Comment: Look into `Linq GroupBy`. Why do you have a vb.net tag but declare items with c# syntax? Also, it'd be good to add webforms to your tags, just guessing that's what your using.

Comment: This could help: [Databind repeater with group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508051/databind-repeater-using-linq-with-group-by)

Comment: Oh, yea I guess I wrote the items out in C# syntax by habit.  I'm working on a legacy project in VB.Net which I pretty much never work with.

Yes, it is in webforms.  I will add that to the tag.  I will also look at the link you supplied.  Thank you very much.